# iPhone : parallax scroll effect like wp7 metro ui

Tags: iphone, scroll, microsoft-metro, parallax

for an iOs app I'd like to recreate the parallax effect of hubs in Windows Phone 7.
I can reach it by using this code :

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    CGRect lc_frame = hubBackgroundImageView.frame;
    lc_frame.origin.x=-hubItemsScrollView.contentOffset.x/2;
    hubBackgroundImageView.frame = lc_frame;
}
```

But the effect is not perfect. In WP7, on the last page of a hub, the right side of the background image perfectly fit the right side of the view.

Here, if my image is smaller than my scrollview width/2, I can see my viewController backgroundColor...

[image: screenshot]

I would like to get the new x position of the image depending on the scrollview contentSize.width, image.frame.size.width and the new scrollview.contentOffset.x.
The goal is that on the last page of the scrollview my background image position is

```
backgroundImage.frame.origin.x = -backgroundImage.frame.size.width+self.view.frame.size.width;
```

Please, help me ! Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it ! Here is my function :

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    float paralaxPlacementRatio=scrollView.contentOffset.x/(scrollView.contentSize.width-scrollView.frame.size.width);

    CGRect lc_frame = backgroundImageView.frame;
    lc_frame.origin.x=-backgroundImageView.frame.size.width*paralaxPlacementRatio+(self.view.frame.size.width*paralaxPlacementRatio);
    backgroundImageView.frame = lc_frame;
}
```

My view's structure is:

- backgroundImageView (UIImageView that I don't know the width)
- scrollView (UIScrollView pageEnabled that I don't know the contentSize.width)

The result is perfect, if anyone want an explanation, ask me !